# Change Excel new line character

Tags: excel, newline

I have a file that looks like this:

```
------------
comment1
------------
comment2 part 1
comment2 part 2
------------
comment3
```

I'd like to import this file in Excel. By default, Excel treats new lines as new rows, so by default I obtain this:

```
A ------------
B comment1
C ------------
D comment2 part 1
E comment2 part 2
F ------------
G comment3
```

However, I want to specify a different new line character, which is (for example) "-----------". With this role I would obtain:

```
A comment1
B comment2 part 1
  comment2 part 2
C comment3
```

Any way to solve this?

**MY SOLUTION:**
Since (apparently) there is not a way to define a different "end line character" in Excel, I had to surround my comments with the character `"`, so it became:

```
A ------------
B "comment1"
C ------------
D "comment2 part 1
E comment2 part 2"
F ------------
G "comment3"
```

In this way Excel understood that part1 and part2 were in the same cell.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using VBA to read the file's contents and parse it accordingly.

Comment: If it's a "one of" deal there are plenty of workarounds, or is this something you'd do frequently?

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to combine the info. into one cell? If you plan on doing almost anything with the data/comments later, it'll be a bit of a pain to deal with.

Comment: So, the problem is that in one cell I can have multiple lines. So instead of using the common `\n` to separate the cells, I used a personal one (in the example is `----------------`). I thought that Excel had a way to specify the "End of the line" character